# Samba 4 DNS not syncing with Windows DNS

Tags: dns, samba4

I set up a couple of months ago a Samba 4 AD DC and in the beginning it seemed to be working good but now I am receiving that Samba 4 DNS is not resolving external DNS requests line cnn.com. It seems like it is not making use of the root DNS servers and it is not resolving newly added internal DNS records. How can I fix this issue? I had to point the primary DNS back to the Windows DNS Server. Our goal is to replace all Windows Servers with Linux Solutions. Please advise

Comment: The Samba AD DC dns server does not use root dns servers, it forwards anything outside the AD domain to an external dns server e.g. Googles 8.8.8.8 Have you got a 'dns forwarder' line in smb.conf (if using the internal dns server) or 'forwarders' set in your named.conf (if using Bind9)

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes the forwarder directive is set to use the other internal Windows DNS Servers, let me change that to use Public DNS Servers instead. Ill update with the results ...

Comment: Thank you adjusting the forwarders resolved the issue